# Flexslider navigation control size

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I have implemented the [FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) slider. It works great but I cant seem to find how to make the navigational "dots" smaller or bigger.

I was hoping it used images but I cant find the images, I think they are created dynamicly using JS.

Something like below would be perfect

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({

       navigationDotSize: '30px',

    start: function(slider){}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me,
I should know by now CSS does all this. haha

.flex-control-paging li a {width: 30px; height: 30px; }